# WindowState.Maximized at window event `Loaded`

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have two monitors setup. In my application i have simple `DXWindow` with properties `WindowState`, `Width`, `Height`, `Left` and `Right` binded to its `DataContext`. At the event Loaded i set `Width`, `Height`, `Left`, `Right` and `WindowState` that loaded from setting. Then, if `WindowState.Maximized` is set, window becomes bugged:[image]

Window is maximized at monitor 2, BUT it kinda exist on two monitors at a time, so that debug `pin` appeared in the middle of two monitors. That problem then appears at dialog windows, they rendered at two monitors at a time, but main window is maximized at monitor 2.

Comment: "debug pin" is murky.  The arrow points to the XAML tree visualizer.  It is a debugging aid that has nothing to do with your code.  That it shows up in an awkward place surely has something to do with your program using two monitors.  If you want it somewhere else then you'll have to file a bug with Microsoft.

Comment: I know how to use that `pin`, the main problem here is a dialog window that appears at two monitors at the same time, but main window is maximized at monitor 2.

Answer (score 0):

Moved loading window position code to window constructor solved the problem.